# i want to match dot after string regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to match character by character after a string: `word`

> wordtsssrrggmnvk

match t,  match s, match s, ...

I'm trying to use `(?<=word).` but it does not work.

Comment: What language are you using? Regex isn't a good fit for this because it has to recheck for `word` for every character. Just get the substring after `word`, and then split to a character array.

Comment: Only regex engines which support quantifiers in look-behinds seem to work here. `(?<=word.*).` works for me in .NET

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? If you look at the description for the `regex` tag, it says that "all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool." Can you please tell what regex engine you're using so that we know what *would* work?

Comment: i want to match  the characters  after  word , one by one                  s,s,s,r,r,g,g,m,n,v,k

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Notepad++'s PCRE engine. If it's a tedious task, you might be able to copy-paste the text after putting the text in a separate file and then matching with `.`, doing the operation, and then pasting the text back in place.

Comment: ok thanks for your answers
long ago I did something similar but in reverse direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++, you have the powerful Boost regex engine. One of its features is the `\G` operator support that lets you perform a global search (=match multiple occurrences) of a successive pattern upon a successful match. Also, a very nice operator coming from Perl is `\K` that omits all the text matched so far within the current regex iteration.

So, you need

```
(?:\G(?!^)|word)\K.
```

To enable `.` to match a newline, check the *`.` matches a newline* checkbox.

**Explanation**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|word)` - Match the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or the string `word`
- `\K` - omit the matched text (i.e. `word`)
- `.` - matches any character other than a newline (LF).

Here is a test where each found character is prepended with a hyphen (replacement pattern is `-$0`):

[image]

Comment: `(?<=word).` won't work as it only matches a char other than a newline that is immediately preceded with `word` text. Also, if you need to match `word` at the start of a line only, use `^word` in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

`^word(.*)` will capture everything after word

http://rubular.com/r/9tG61DCsry

As @4castle metioned, get the substring and split:

```
var word = "wordtsssrrggmnvk";

wordMatch = word.match(/^word(.*)/);
charArray = wordMatch[1].split("")

console.log(charArray)
// ["t", "s", "s", "s", "r", "r", "g", "g", "m", "n", "v", "k"]
```